# I want to set attributes to "span" element when the mouse move over "a" element

Tags: css

I want to set attributes to "span" element when the mouse move over "a" element

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftmenu">
        <li><a id="menu1" href="#"><span class="iconic menu11"></span></a></li>
        <li><a id="menu2" href="#"><span class="iconic menu22"></span></a></li>
        <li><a id="menu3" href="#"><span class="iconic menu33"></span></a></li>
        <li><a id="menu4" href="#"><span class="iconic menu44"></span></a></li>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>


#leftmenu li  a span{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:45px;
    line-height:45px;
    color: transparent;
    background-color: #CF9D9B;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0 1px 2px;
}
```

this not working:

```
#leftmenu li a:hover span {
    color: transparent;
    background-color: #0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four 0's in your hover background-color definition; change it to 3 (shorthand) or 6 (full hex colour code).

That then works for me if I put something in a span to see - e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/sync/QKn9v/